# How to run Docker container interactively on Azure

Tags: r, azure, docker

I am trying to run R interactively on Azure Docker container. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.cascadia-analytics.com/2018/07/21/docker-r-p1.html).
In release CLI I added `-ti --rm` as per tutorial. Here is how command looks

```
az container create --resource-group some_endless_details

az container start --resource-group some_resource_group_name --name my_demo_container  -ti --rm
```

My Dockerfile contains has just one line `FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.2`

My release fails with the following error:

```
UnrecognizedArgumentError: unrecognized arguments: -ti --rm
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If yes please accept it.

Comment: Why not give any updates and also do not accept it? Do you still work on this question?

Comment: @CharlesXu  sorry for delay, I simply did not have time to test your solution. I accepted your answer and will test later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you just want to create a docker environment that can run the R application. And you want to deploy the docker container on ACI and interact with it. Unfortunately, ACI does not support the parameters like `-it` and `--rm` like docker. The right way to interact with the ACI is that creates a bash connection with the ACI. You need to do two steps.

1. create the ACI with the CLI:

   az container create -g group_name -n container_name --image rocker/r-ver:4.0.2 --ip-address public --command-line "tail -f /dev/null"
2. create a bash connection with the ACI:

   az container exec -g group_name -n container_name --exec-command "/bin/bash"

Generally, you can create a bash connection with the existing ACI with the second command, but in my test, it seems the command cannot create the connection. So I recommend you go to the Azure portal and find the ACI, then you can choose the connect and select the `/bin/bash` and it will look like this:

[image]