# container from rocker/r-ver:4.0.4 exists after run command

Tags: r, docker

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.4
```

In cmd I build:

```
docker build -t myfolder/myimage .
```

and it builds image just fine.

Then I run

```
docker run myfolder/myimage
```

it produces:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library Book"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

>
```

and exits immediately. So it loads R as it is supposed to, but why does it exit?

Comment: You probably want to run this interactively, e.g. with `docker run -it myfolder/myimage`

Comment: @camille Thank you, you are absolutely right, `-t` worked. Now I have to same problem on Azure.

Comment: Look at the dockerfile: its command when you call `docker run` is just `R` with no further arguments. When you add that you want it to run interactively with TTY support from the command line, you were able to give commands interactively to R. I don't know much about Azure, but are you trying to run commands interactively there as well, or should you be running a pre-written script?

Comment: @camille, I would like to run pre-written script on Azure, but for now I troubleshooting and need to run it interactively. I cannot find corresponding interactive command for Azure.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know much about Azure, but the top result in a quick search was this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65330723/5325862